# world coordinates to camera coordinates to pixel coordinates

Tags: opencv, projection

I am trying to project a giving 3D point to image plane, I have posted many question regarding this and many people help me, also I read many related links but still the projection doesn't work for me correctly.

I have a 3d point (-455,-150,0) where x is the **depth** axis and z is the **upwards** axis and y is the **horizontal** one I have **roll: Rotation around the front-to-back axis (x)** , **pitch: Rotation around the side-to-side axis (y)** and **yaw:Rotation around the vertical axis (z)** also I have the position on the camera (x,y,z)=(-50,0,100) so I am doing the following 
first I am doing from world coordinates to camera coordinates using the extrinsic parameters:

```
    double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double yp = 0.033716827630996704* pi / 180; //roll
    double thet = 67.362312316894531* pi / 180; //pitch
    double k = 89.7135009765625* pi / 180;      //yaw
    double rotxm[9] = { 1,0,0,0,cos(yp),-sin(yp),0,sin(yp),cos(yp) };
    double rotym[9] = { cos(thet),0,sin(thet),0,1,0,-sin(thet),0,cos(thet) };
    double rotzm[9] = { cos(k),-sin(k),0,sin(k),cos(k),0,0,0,1};
    cv::Mat rotx = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotxm };
    cv::Mat roty = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotym };
    cv::Mat rotz = Mat{ 3,3,CV_64F,rotzm };
    cv::Mat rotationm = rotz * roty * rotx; //rotation matrix 
    cv::Mat mpoint3(1, 3, CV_64F, { -455,-150,0 }); //the 3D point location 
    mpoint3 = mpoint3 * rotationm; //rotation 
    cv::Mat position(1, 3, CV_64F, {-50,0,100}); //the camera position 
    mpoint3=mpoint3 - position; //translation
```

and now I want to move from camera coordinates to image coordinates

**the first solution was**: as I read from some sources

```
Mat myimagepoint3 = mpoint3 * mycameraMatrix;
```

this didn't work

**the second solution was**:

```
double fx = cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0);
double fy = cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 1);
double  cx1 = cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 2);
double cy1= cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 2);
xt = mpoint3 .at<double>(0) / mpoint3.at<double>(2);
yt = mpoint3 .at<double>(1) / mpoint3.at<double>(2);
double u = xt * fx + cx1;
double v = yt * fy + cy1;
```

but also didn't work

I also tried to use opencv method fisheye::projectpoints(from world to image coordinates)

```
 Mat recv2;
 cv::Rodrigues(rotationm, recv2);
 //inputpoints a vector contains one point which is the 3d world coordinate of the point
 //outputpoints a vector to store the output point
 cv::fisheye::projectPoints(inputpoints,outputpoints,recv2,position,mycameraMatrix,mydiscoff );
```

but this also didn't work

by didn't work I mean: I know (in the image) where should the point appear but when I draw it, it is always in another place (not even close) sometimes I even got a negative values

note: there is no syntax errors or exceptions but may I made typos while I am writing code here
so can any one suggest if I am doing something wrong?